# Linear discriminant analysis-Do we maximize posterior or joint distribution?

Tags: machine-learning, discriminant-analysis

My understanding is that in LDA, we maximize the joint density $ P(X,y) $ using $P(X|y)$ rather than posterior density $P(y|X)$ using $P(X|y)$. In the book "Introduction to Statistical learning with R", the authors say otherwise. Though they do not provide a derivation, they say the expressions for $P(y|X)$ are to be maximised.

https://hastie.su.domains/ISLR2/ISLRv2_website.pdf

See equation 4.15 and 4.17 and paragraphs around them.

Answer (score 0):

Maximizing the joint density is equivalent to maximizing the posterior because the denominator is the common term across classes, i.e. $P(X)$. In addition to  $P(X|y)$, $P(y)$ is also used in the process as class prior.

Comment: Your argument works for prediction 'after' the estimates are done. However, the estimates for $\mu_k$ etc are done by maximizing the joint density (by multiplying over all observations). If we want to take partial derivatives of posterior instead of joint distribution, the expressions become very complicated due to the denominator.